# How to show error message only on the element the user click in ngFor Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to show a message when user didn't select an option from the dropdown menu, I have managed to make it work however I want it to only show on the element where you click the button rather than showing it all at the same time.

Question is how can I only show the error message when I only click `Test 1` data within `ngFor` and vice versa if I click `Test 2`?

data for `ngFor` just a sample json to illustrate my question.

```
this.data= [
  {
    'name': 'Test 1',
    'id': '1',
    'img' 'http://placehold.it/350x150',
    "size": ['4', '4.5', '5', '5.5', '6', '6.5', '7', '7.5']
  },
  {
    'name': 'Test 2',
    'id': '2',
    'img' 'http://placehold.it/350x150',
    "size": ['4', '4.5', '5', '5.5', '6', '6.5', '7', '7.5']
  }
]
```

Component function code to determine whether user has selection none in the dropdown menu.

```
xdMessage: Boolean = false;
showError (size) {
 if(size == '0') {
   this.xdMessage = true;
   console.log(size);
   // show message string error message
 } else {
   console.log(size);
   this.errMessage = false;
   //show OK string message
 }
}
```

Template view --

```
<div class="col-sm-6" *ngFor="let x of data"> 
    <h2 class="pull-left"> {{ x.name }}</h2>
    <button class="pull-right" (click)="showError(selectSizeCtrl.value);"> Show Message </button>
    <p *ngIf="selectSizeCtrl.value == '0' && !!xdMessage "> Select a size! Error Message! </p>
    <select name="" id="size" class="form-control" #selectSizeCtrl ngControl="selectSizeCtrl">
        <option value="0">Select Id</option>
        <option *ngFor="let xd of x.size" [value]="xd"> {{ xd }}</option>
    </select>
    <img src="{{ x.img }}" alt="" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
```

Perhaps my example will explain my situation a little bit better.
[Plnkr sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/lJzTiCaKEbqg1cjQz1UN?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing your whole usecase, so this might not be a suitable solution, but maybe is. So we could introduce a new property in `x`, let's say named `clicked`. So we conditionally only show message for that `x`, which the `clicked` property is `true`. So pass `x` in your `showError`-function and modify it to the following:

```ts
showError (size, x) { 
  for(let i=0; i< this.data.length; i++){
    this.data[i].clicked= false; // set all other to false;
  }
  x.clicked = true; // chosen is true

  if(size == '0') {
    this.xdMessage = true;
    console.log(size);
    // show message string error message
  } else {
    console.log(size);
    this.errMessage = false;
    //show OK string message
  }
}
```

and then in your template, just wrap your error message in a div:

```html
<div *ngIf="x.clicked">
  <p *ngIf="selectSizeCtrl.value == '0' && !!xdMessage "> 
      Select a size! Error Message! 
  </p>
</div>
```

Your forked

### [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Uh19tJEvYbxOpwktIxgp?p=preview)

Comment: ah damn just that -.- I was almost on the right track then. Thanks

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code, the `showError()` function will be triggered when you click either on of the button since both shared in same component. Therefore, both tests will generate the result accordingly at the same time.

You should make a nested component for both data so each test will have separated component.

on the `app.ts`, you should pass all of the data to another component, for example based on your code this is the template,

```
<div class="container">
   <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
   <my-nested-app *ngFor="let x of data" [x]="x"></my-nested-app>
</div>
```

this code will create separated component that using `my-nested-app` selector with each `x` data.

the `[x]="x"` means that you pass all the `x` to be used to another component then you should create a new component. For my example, I created `src/nested.ts` that received each `x` input that have `my-nested-app` selector,

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-nested-app'
```

In the template, you can put the template you are using inside the `*ngFor` div and inside the class, get the `x` variable using `@Input()` and put all the function.

```
export class NestedComponent {
  @Input() x;
  xdMessage: Boolean = false;

  showError (size) {
    if(size == '0') {
      this.xdMessage = true;
      console.log(size);
      // show message string error message
    } else {
      console.log(size);
      this.errMessage = false;
      //show OK string message
    }
  }
}
```

Back to `src/app.ts` import the `NestedComponent` class and put it in tehe declarations,

```
import {NestedComponent} from './nested'

@NgModule({
  ...
  declarations: [ App, NestedComponent ],
  ...
})
```

You can see the the example code here [Plunkr Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/4bfvi6eFEtQ3fWDP1bDK?p=preview)

Comment: Is nesting the only way? I want to put the `showError` in the service at it will be use in other components.